# Generate typescript @summary from [annotation] in dotnet

Tags: .net, typescript, swagger, code-generation, nswag

I have a set of DTOs, that can be either submitted or received by the client in an api call.
The way, that we synchronize between client<-> server DTOs is using NSwag, which generates a `client.ts` file, containing all of the types and actions.
It already parses xml documentation and includes them in the appropriate places.

I've added the following `RequiredAttribute`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)] 
public class RequiredAttribute : Attribute 
{ 
    public RequiredAttribute(RequiredFlag flags) 
    {
         Flags = flags;
     }  
    public RequiredFlag Flags { get; } 
}
```

this attribute is used like this:

```
public class SomeDTO
{
    [Required(RequiredFlag.Get)] 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(RequiredFlag.Get)] 
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'd like to inform NSwag that it should basically take this `[Required(RequiredFlag.Get)]`  and place it over the generated api endpoint, to get something like this in the generated typescript

```
/** 
  * @param id
 * @return SomeDTO
 * @required<SomeDTO, Id | Name>
  */
 someDTOGet(id: number): Promise<SomeDTO> {
```

I'm somewhat experienced in dotnet, but unfamiliar with NSwag.

Diving the NSwag docs to find an existing pattern, but there does not seem to be one